# how to implement a repository of algorithms?

Tags: java, design-patterns, repository, repository-design

I have a set of algorithms implemented in Java and packaged as jar files. The algorithms are intended for 3rd party to access them. The algorithms have several variations. Overtime, new versions and new types of algorithms will be added to. At the same time I don't wont all the 3rd parties to be forced to use the new algorithm.

I am considering implement a simple repository system for this. The requirements are as follows:

1. create/delete of the repos, so that each repo contain one set of variations of the algorithm.
2. algorithms in one repos can have serverl versions running at the same time.
3. new algorithms can be added to the a repo.

Is there some open source project fit my requirement? Or is there some design pattern for problems like this?

Comment: Search for interfaces and factories. (Funny you should mention `design pattern`.)

Comment: I think interfaces and factories only abstract the external behavior of the repo, but I am thinking about a best practice for the internal mechanism of the repo. e.g. How to package different versions of the algorithms into a jar. How to store them, how to address a specific version, etc.

Comment: For one given algorithm, is each version implemented in a separate class (distinct fully qualified name) ?

Comment: I prefer not to because I do not want to couple the version with the class name. The version should be determined only at release time.

Comment: Bunch of questions before finding out a solution - Do you have a datastore? Do you already have any design patterns included in the algorithm implementations? Did you use any DI / IOC patterns with it?

Comment: Depending on the abstraction level of the algorithms you might have a look on the [service provider interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) provided by the API.

Answer (score 2):

As one example, *Apache Commons Lang* solved this problem by changing their package name between the 2.0 and 3.0 versions:
`org.apache.commons.lang` became `org.apache.commons.lang3`.

From [What's new in Commons Lang 3.0?](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html)

> We've removed the deprecated parts of the API and have also removed
>   some features that were deemed weak or unnecessary. All of this means
>   that Lang 3.0 is not backwards compatible.
>
> To that end we have changed the package name, allowing Lang 3.0 to sit
>   side-by-side with your previous version of Lang without any bad side
>   effects.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern-based solution would be, as suggested in several comments, declaring interfaces and implementing factories:

For each algorithm, you should:

- Declare its own interface, which should endure in time in a conservative way: Althrough new versions, preserve always the existing API without modification (so the old code can always use it). If needed, add *new* methods.
- Code an implementation for each version you want to support. This implementations must have *package* visibility, and they can share the same package but having each one its own name, of corse.
- Then, add a factory to build implementation objects. This factory should recive as a parameter the desired version:

`public class MyFactory
    {
        public MyInterface create(String version) throws VersionNotSupportedException {...}
    }`

About coding this factory, I also suggest you to add in every JAR a `META-INF/myfile` with the mapping between versions and implementation classes, so that `MyFactory` could get them all executing:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResources("META-INF/myfile");
```

Going further, you can declare a *generic factory* parametrizing the type of the returned objects:

```
public class MyGenericFactory<T>
{
    public T create(String version) throws VersionNotSupportedException {...}
}
```